# Getting error while using html page instead of jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc

I wanted to use `html` page instead of using `jsp` page. But while using html page I am getting error. But if I use jsp page i don't get any error.

When I use  `<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>`I don't get any error.  Here my `spring-servlet.xml` file

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
>
> ```
> <mvc:annotation-driven/>
> <context:component-scan base-package="org.avijit"/>
> <bean id="jspViewResolver"
>       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
>     <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
>     <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
> </bean>
> ```

My `Controller` class is

> ```
>  package org.avijit;
>     import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
>     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
>     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
>
>     @Controller
>     public class BaseController {
>         @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
>         public String homePage()
>         {
>             return "welcomePage";
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: What is the content of `welcomePage.html`?

Answer (score 1):

At last i got an answer. I have changed my `viewresolver` class to

```
<bean
        id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/"
        p:suffix=".html"
        p:templateMode="HTML5"

></bean>

<bean id="templateEngine"
      class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
</bean>
```

Now everything working fine ! :)